# How to fill NaN values by considering average of previous 2 observations

Tags: python, pandas, nan, lag

I am using the following code to fill NaN values in pandas. This df has different climatic variables (temperature, humidity, rainfall, vegetation...)

```
df1[var_list]= df1[var_list].fillna(df1[var_list].rolling(3, min_periods=1).mean())
```

I want to fill NaNs with average of previous 2 values in that column. In some part of df i have continuous 8 NaNs, so the above code just fills for first 2 NaN. Which is correct output for the code given above.

But i want to fill all NaNs(may be taking average of imputed NaN values? - but i don't know how to do this as i am new to python). Is there a better way to do this. I will be using time lagged inputs to my ML models so i can't drop any observation.

var_list ==> contains list of variables which have NaNs

Answer (score 0):

It won't be perfect, but you could do something very close to this with two steps:

1. Do your current rolling average computation, as above
2. Fill forward (`.ffill()`)

While your first step will only fill NAs that occur directly after values, the second step will fill from there.

*However* I am not sure how this will handle a case were NAs come after a single value, e.g.

```
3 2 NaN NaN 3 NaN NaN
```

It sounds like you'd want those last two NaNs to be set to 2.5, but this method would probably set them to 3 (since the rolling average won't have enough preceding elements to fill them). So ultimately it depends on whether you're willing to alter your methodology a little.

Answer (score 0):

I guess a simple joe approach could be to do it over and over until no NaNs are left by doing a check

```
while df1.isnull().values.any() is True:
    df1[var_list]= df1[var_list].fillna(df1[var_list].rolling(3, min_periods=1).mean())
```